# What happens when bjt beta is infinity?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, bjt

What happens when bjt beta infinity? Is it in saturation or cut off or active mode?

Comment: Nope, the questions only let us know the resistors around the circuit

Comment: The BJT parameters are independent of the circuit mode. However, you can only *measure* beta in one of those modes.

Comment: So can i assume the circuit is in active mode?

Comment: And the base current is zero?

Comment: What's any finite collector current divided by an infinite beta?

Comment: When the gain is dependent on R ratios, with sufficient hFE , more make little difference. When hFE does matter, it probably saturates some ccts and cuts off others

Comment: In a robustly biassed transistor circuit, you'll see barely any change in the bias conditions between assuming a beta of 100, and infinity. Most 'small signal' transistors have a beta > 100.

Comment: Assuming the collector current is finite then base current, \$I_B = \lim_{\beta\to\infty} \left(\frac{I_C}{\beta}\right) \rightarrow 0\$. Assuming base current is finite then collector current, \$I_C = \lim_{\beta\to\infty} \left(I_B \cdot \beta\right) \rightarrow \infty\$. So, what can we say about this? Well, for the second situation, infinite collector current shows a short, so we can say that transistor is well saturated (i.e. switch behavior & zero C-E resistance). But for the first situation, it can be in active region. Please someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Rohat Kilic, I am afraid you are a victim of misinterpreting the relation IC=beta*IB. It must be read: IB=IC/beta.

Comment: By the way: From the famous Barrie Gilber I have learned that at Analog Devices they have fabricated (and tested) bipolar transistors with B values of several thousands.

Comment: gold doping on junctions was used in the 2N5088 to raise hfe at the expense  of  BW. hfe value range up to 1400 with GBW=50MHz and the 2N5089 was higher as I recall. These were useful for audio amp front & intermediate stages.

Comment: @Tony Stewart - are you sure they were gold doped? I thought gold doping was used to reduce carrier lifetime that sped up diodes and reduced storage time in transistors but at the expense of Hfe.

Comment: I was sure back in '76 but thinking now you are correct, other factors increased the hfe over 1000 and gold doping was to compensate for the severe loss in GBW bandwidth so gold was added just to get 50MHz GBW unlike the lower hfe 2N2222 with 200MHz GBW but the gold added noise, so NG for pre-amps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "ideal" realworld BJT has a beta not of two, but 200 or more.

So, doesn't this mean that modern signal-level BJTs must always be cut off?  And, we should only use 1950s BJTs with their low betas?  Of course not.

Go and build a diff-amp; long-tail pair.  Works just fine with infinite beta.  Differential pairs are based on voltage-input, Vbe1-Vbe2.  Your infinite-beta diff-amp won't have any input bias current, similar to MOS-input op-amps, yay.  Same with emitter-follower, cascode amps, etc.  All these have FET versions, and all would work better if Ib=0.   Perhaps even current-mirrors would still work (by transferring a Vbe, with infinitesimal current?  Hmm.)   In other words, look inside any BJT op-amp, and check whether any of the stages will malfunction if the Ebers-Moll equation Vbe-->Ic still applied, yet also the Ib became zero for all values of Vbe.

Also, go read the BJT chapters of Art of Electronic textbook, which counsels us to avoid the distorted hfe-based thinking taught in technician courses.

Engineers instead treat BJTs as voltage-input devices, where beta represents an unwanted leakage factor, a non-infinite input impedance caused by non-ideal base thickness.  (Ideally base thickness would go to zero, giving infinite BE impedance, yet not experience punch-through.)

PS

What's the 'beta' of a JFET?  Hey everyone go design a JFET common-source amplifier with a large series resistor on its gate lead, then feed it a voltage signal which creates the correct number of picoamperes when given an input bias of, say, 24V.  Now breathe on it, or take it outdoors, and the change in humidity (surface-leakage) will drive it crazy.  It's a bad design based on gate current rather than gate voltage.  The same issues apply to BJT designs, where we can view Ib as being an unwanted leakage current.  So, don't design with capacitor-isolated CE stages; design with diff-amp stages.  (Heh, I repaired someone's high power audio amp.  The entire thing was a giant op-amp constructed from discretes!  This to provide ideal bass response going down to DC, with no capacitors needed to separate the several AC gain stages. That's voltage-input design philosophy.

Those trapped in "hfe-think" will look at the internal schematic of LM741 and recoil in confusion, as if it was designed by alien minds, or perhaps satan himself.  (It was!  Total blasphemous concepts, where BJTs are voltage-input stages and hfe is irrelevant.)

PPS

Why did William Shockley describe BJTs as current-driven devices?  Why is it called "Ebers-Moll equation," when Shockley damn well should have written their paper instead?  Maybe he just didn't see?  Speculation: Shockley well knew that BJTs were transconductors, but he was terrified of having his patents thrown out, because the transistor had been patented 20 years before, and it was an FET.  Patent reviewers and judges might not see any major difference between 1945 BJTs and the 1925 FETs, and reject the Bell Labs patents based on prior art.  What to do?  Easy: declare that BJTs are current-input, totally different than vacuum tubes (and different than Lilienfeld's MOSFET,) then hype the hell out of it constantly and everywhere.  If true, then there's no way that Shockley could publish systems of equations demonstrating that Vbe determines the BE potential barrier, and hence controls Ie and Ic.

Comment: wbeaty, thank for these clear words. Since many years I try to convince some people (believing (!!) in strict current-control) that the BJT is, of course, a voltage-controlled elenent. It seems that this question is a kind of "religion".

Comment: Sorry for so many typos. I lost my concentration,,,,

Comment: @LvW Here's AOA author Win Hill himself, about "current controlled" transistors: http://cr4.globalspec.com/comment/720374/Re-Voltage-vs-Current  also  http://cr4.globalspec.com/comment/720033/Re-Voltage-vs-Current.   Note that as a 1960s newbie engineer, Hill found he couldn't design stable BJT circuits.  Finally a more experienced engineer took him aside and told him the great secret:  transistors are voltage-input, same as FETs and vacuum tubes.  Yes, "hfe-thinking" is a hotly-defended irrational belief-system which ignores basic physics. In other words, a religion.

Comment: @Winfield Hill, thank you for the message. I know both linked contributions since some years - and I have used them very often as a reference to support my view. But it is very hard to fight against such a "beautiful" equation like Ic=B*Ib. Even observable/measurable effects cannot help (transconductance, RE-feedback, tan-h for diff. amp, -2mV/K, EARLY effect,...)

Comment: @LvW you are building a straw man, here. The reason you are "fighting hard" is because you believe that voltage control is the *only* way to explain how transistor works and it all boils down to your belief that the Ebers-Moll equations instate a cause-effect relationship. Well, that is not the case: just go on Physics Stack Exchange and do a search for "cause-effect". By the way, did you even manage to read *all* the reference you posted http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~hu/Chenming-Hu_ch8.pdf ?

Comment: No - I do not only "believe". I am convinced - and I can justify my opinion. Have you any counter arguments? And - yes - I did read all the mentioned documents. Did YOU read page 297 of the linked document?

Comment: Have you tried searching on Physics Stack Exchange for "cause-effect"? I guess not. Because that's the whole point. As far as the linked document go,  it says "indesirable but *INEVITABLE*". You need that charge. Besides, I wonder what do you make of the charge control model of p. 314 and of example 8.5 "Finding Ic(t) for a step Ib(t)". Try to solve that example without base current.

Comment: @SrendiVashtar charge-control model is a high-frequency refinement of voltage-control model (needed because we have no direct access to potentials within the silicon.) However, there are multiple reasons for confusion.  First, hfe works fine if BJT remains a black box. But open the hood, examine BJT internals, and we find that e-fields accelerate charges, but the reverse doesn't exist: it's an entropy violation. Vbe determines Ie. This is separate from misconceptions taught at early grades and then persisting (wrong idea that Ib directly controls Ic, when there is no such mechanism.)

Comment: @wbeaty, the fact that it is a refinement is of no concern here. It shows that you can model the behavior of the transistor without considering Vbe. I would like to hear more about this entropy violation though. So far it appears that you too think that voltage causes current. So we can take all this to a far simpler device. A diode, or even a resistor. Would you say that in V = R I voltage causes current?

Comment: @Sredni Vashtar, I do not rely upon artificial models - I am an engineer and rely upon observable effects and measurements (RE-fedback, gain formula with transconductance, tempco -2mV/K, EARLY effect, current mirror, B. Gilbert´s translinear loops,..).

Comment: @Sredni Vashtar, Quote: "As far as the linked document go, it says "indesirable but INEVITABLE". So what? What do you want to proove? No part and no circuit is ideal. Each element/circuit has parasitics - they are INEVITABLE! They influence the desired behaviour but they do not necessarily determine the working principle!That is a big difference!

Comment: It is inevitable because if you want to sustain a particular value of Vbe you HAVE TO supply a certain value of Ib. V and I are two sides of the same coin: power transfer. Even at the most elementary level you can't move charge without a field but you can't have a field without displacing charge. The battery that gives you a voltage, has to displace charge in its guts in order to keep that equilibrium value, once the load starts to draw current. What causes what?

Comment: Nobody denies the existence of a base current. But it is the voltage across the depletion region which determines the width of this zone - and, hence, the collector current.

Comment: ...and you finally managed to put it back to square one. I guess there is no use in repeating myself. You can go up this post and re-read the comments.

Comment: @SredniVashtar Vbe adjusts the potential-hill which determines Ic, but we can also say that a constant-current Ib supply determines Vbe. Ib only affects Ic through intermediate Vbe potential hill.  Abstraction: ignore Vbe, say Ib directly determines Ic. Also, in resistors, at the micro-level, net acceleration of carriers is produced by a potential-hill (an e-field,) and proportional to resistivity, like tilting a fuzzy board covered with rolling marbles. The acceleration of the charges does not cause the "tilt," so, yes, voltage causes current inside resistors. At the macro level we ignore it.

Comment: @wbeaty, I know all that. But you are starting from the given that an external potential (or field) is supplied and remains unaltered. But if you look at the whole picture you have to ask yourself: how do we keep the voltage that causes current if not by displacing charges? Physics laws are not cause-effect relationships, unless you can put time somewhere in the equations. But I was honestly interested in your argument about entropy. That could be a killer (I don't remember who said "if your theory goes against the second principle of thermodynamics, then..." but I believe he was right)

Comment: To be clear: I am not stating that the egg comes before the chicken. I am saying that this is an egg-chicken problem.

Comment: @SredniVashtar wherever voltage causes current, just "reverse the movie" and current causes voltage. Impossible with resistors or fwd-biased diodes: violates entropy. "Rolling downhill," same as leaky dielectrics, both are forward-time thermodynamics.|| I think you're stuck as long as you believe that currents of the distant past can cause voltage in the present. (Capacitor: voltage without current. What's "causing" capacitor voltage? Net charge. Not currents of the past.) Confronting mistakes shatters the edifice. Rebuild an improved explanation, find that Art of Electronics already had that.

Comment: @wbeaty, time does not appear at all in my vision - that's in fact the point. What I meant by "how do we keep the voltage that causes the current if not by displacing charges" basically meant "you have to close the circuit". When you close your circuit battery-resistor you see that the battery can reinstate its internal equilibrium only if the charge 'coming out' of one pole is getting back from the other pole. That's how voltage and current are so intimately related. There is a nice explanation of how a battery works in a circuit in Kip's "Fundamentals of Electricity and Magnetism 2e".

Comment: To answer your question: the capacitor voltage Vmax is "caused" by the open circuit current I=0. Let a current flow, and tell me what happens to your voltage. ("Caused" is obviously in quotes in my view). And yes, you had to displace charge in some way to charge the cap in the first place, but let's not stick to the past).

Comment: Heh, I was thinking of an oil capacitor, sitting for years on a shelf, still with 1KV across terminals.  "You have to close the circuit" no, you don't, that's no part of physics at all, ever. Show me a text that teaches it.  (I've encountered it as a grade-school electricity misconception, the wrong idea that "voltage always needs current," or that "voltage is really just a part of a current."  Wrong, voltage is a separate thing, it's the e-fields, with no connection to charge-motion.  Note that a charged particle has a voltage, a few hundred KV.  Where there's e-field, there must be voltage)

Comment: @wbeaty you have to close the circuit to get charge back to the the battery if you want a current to flow (incidentally, this is what distinguish BJTs from FETs: the latter do not require a current in base/gate - allow me to ignore tunneling) and keep that voltage value. If you do not want current, leave the circuit open: the voltage was created by the initial displacement of charge and the internal dynamical equilibrium between ions is what keep the battery voltage constant for the special case of I=0. Kip really does a nice job in explaining this in reasonable detail. I am out of chars here.

Comment: As far as your cap goes: your Vmax is there for the special case of I=0. Let the current flow by closing the circuit on a (resistive) load and you'll discover that the voltage will drop. What caused the change in voltage? The current? And what caused the current? The voltage? And... As I said: egg-chicken problem. (Also note that I have no problem with increasing entropy due to the heating of a resistor by a battery or a charged cap: there's power transfer and the power has two faces: V and I, none of which is the cause of the other - or if you will one causes the other and vice-versa.)

Answer (score 4):

> What happens when bjt beta infinity?

Nothing for well-designed circuits.

Beta, or the current gain of a BJT, can vary significantly between units of the same model.  Most datasheets tell you the minimum guaranteed gain at a few operating points, but usually don't spec a maximum gain.  Actual gain of a few parts in a batch can be 10x the minimum guaranteed gain.

Good circuits work with the transistors having from the minimum gain to infinite gain.  Fortunately, that's not hard to design to.  Making sure the circuit works with the minimum gain is usually the part you design to.  In most cases, more gain just works.

For example, consider a simple LED driver:

[image]

Let's say this is a typical green LED and drops 2.1 V.  Figure the transistor will drop 200 mV in saturation, so that leaves 2.7 V across R2 when the LED is on.  That means the current thru R2, and therefore the transistor's collector current, is (2.7 V)/(150 Ω) = 18 mA.

Figure 700 mV B-E drop, so that leaves 2.6 V across R1 when the digital output is high.  The transistor's base current is therefore (2.6 V)/(2.7 kΩ) = 960 µA.

The minimum gain required of the transistor for this circuit to work as intended is therefore (18 mA)/(960 µA) = 19.  What would happen if the transistor gain was 50 instead?  Nothing significantly different.  50 / 19 = 2.6, which means the transistor is getting 2.6 times more base current than needed to stay in saturation.  The C-E saturation voltage may be a little less than the worst case 200 mV figure we used to design the circuit with, but what exactly will that do?  The LED current will be very slightly higher.  Even if the transistor were a perfect switch and had 0 C-E voltage when on, the LED current would only be 19.3 mA instead of the 18 mA when assuming 200 mV saturation.  You wouldn't be able to see the resulting brightness difference, even in a side by side comparison.  There would be more brightness variation between LEDs from the same batch and due to temperature.

Analog circuits work similarly.  For common emitter amplifiers, the input impedance goes up with gain.  Whatever is driving the amplifier input already has to be able to drive the minimum impedance when the transistor happens to have its minimum guaranteed gain.  Driving a higher impedance is usually not a problem.

You can certainly contrive cases where too large a gain makes the circuit not work, but one criterion for good design with BJTs is that this not be the case.  Fortunately, this is usually not hard to achieve.

Comment: Quote: "You can certainly contrive cases where too large a gain makes the circuit not work". Really? Why? Did you read wbeatys answer? I rather think, the BJT wold behave similar to a FET - that`s all.

Comment: @LvW: There are certainly badly designed circuits out there.  I've seen circuits where the bias point was a too dependent on gain, and they wouldn't have worked with infinite gain.  That's just one example.  There are ways of making a mess that have found their way into real designs.  Not everything out there was competently designed, or properly tested across part variations.  Again, it's usually not hard to design with BJTs to tolerate infinite gain, but being immune to infinite gain isn't automatically guaranteed.

Comment: I think, for such a (theoretical) case we have a situation similar to opamp application where we also always need gain stabilizing feedback. Bad designed circuits which do not work can be found also for beta=100. We simply need VBE values in the range of app. =0.7 volts with sufficient RE-stabilization.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I want to invite you to approach the question by comparing the beta in the datasheet with the practical beta(the way you bias the transistor or the circuit conditions).

When you use a beta bigger than what is written on the datasheet, you will put the transistor in cut off mode, because the collector current is too big compared to the base current or the base current is to small to sustain the collector current.

The transistor's \$h_{FE}\$ is given as a range or a few values are listed for reference. By using any of those values you set the transistor in active mode. This one is called "linear beta". If you use anything smaller, you bias the BJT to work in the saturation region when it is paced in the following configuration:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZCXyM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

By using a small beta compared to the linear one, chances are you will always saturate the transistor. All the effects are only related to the above schematic.

Note that the reverse happens for circuits where negative feedback from collector to base is applied:higher beta may bring the BJT closer to saturation(credits to Tony Stewart). However, good designs are independent of this small signal parameter and are not influenced by it.

Comment: When Vce=Vce(sat) or "Saturation" , it depends  on Rc value.  With emitter degeneration (H-bias) or collector feedback, Vce(sat) condition can be avoided by design as a voltage amp rather than a current amp.

Comment: But as a saturated switch, higher hFE improves saturation voltage to some extent limited by rCE due to power rating.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 So the point is that if hFE is bigger, then it will actually be closer to saturation, rather than cut off? State your point clearly and provide evidence, so I can fix the post. If you won't, I'll definitely flag your downvote.

Comment: In an emitter follower, it does not saturate. In an H biased circuit, it never saturates under DC conditions. In a differential pair with a single-ended output and the other tied to Vcc, that one never saturates. Same for any circuit with negative feedback R from collector to base.  Capiche? Of course you can make anything saturate by design.

Comment: Yes closer to saturation and not cut-off but how-much depends on design of circuit to be independent of hFE above a certain level.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 See edit

Answer (score 0):

> What happens when bjt beta infinity? Is it in saturation or cut off or active mode?

if it is indeed infinity, it can be either in saturation (for any Ib>0 -> Ic = infinity) or undefined (for any Ib=0 -> Ic = 0*infinity = undefined).

for a realistic case of large but finite beta, it can be anything.